# Changing Date format through cast and date property of laravel not working on server

Tags: php, laravel, api, date, laravel-5.5

I am building an API using laravel in which I need to show timestamps in d.m.Y g:i a format. I am using

```
protected $dates = [ 'created_on', 'modified_on'];

protected $casts = [
    'created_on' => 'datetime:d.m.Y g:i a',
    'modified_on' => 'datetime:d.m.Y g:i a',
];
```

I have tried this code on my local and it was working fine I can see the changed date format in response of my API's related to the model but when I am testing it on my server, I am getting the Y-m-d format. Where I am doing wrong, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So after checking for every error on earth, I have found that the issue was,  in my local I was using laravel 5.6 but on my server I was using laravel 5.5 . So basically it was all laravel version issue. 
This trick is definitely best for those who wants dates field in the desired format without changing the original format.

Answer (score 0):

The dates property is already casting those fields to Carbon date objects.

Then on top of that you're telling it to cast to a specific format. I recommend picking one or the other.

My recommendation for your API is to store the dates in the standard format- don't apply your custom format to the data in the database (basically, use the dates attribute).

When your API is fetching the data, that is when you convert the date fields into the format you want (check out the Carbon docs- it's way better than the standard datetime object).

Comment: Actually the problem I am facing is that it is not working on server but everything seems to be fine in my local.